# jQuery date picker dialog not working in any version of Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-ui-datepicker

Having a strange issue with the jQuery datepicker. Works fine in Chrome, FF but in Internet Explorer it is rendering like in the attached image, even IE 11, as you can see without the calendar.

[image]

There is no console error when it renders likes this, and I'm initialising with:

```
$('.customDateInput').each(function (idx) {
     var $this = $(this);
     var defaultDate = $this.attr("value").replace(/-/g, ",");
     var $datepicker = $this.parent().find(".datepicker");
     var $spanElement = $this.parent().find(".datepicker-button span");
     (function (picker, altField, defaultDate, spanElement) {
          picker.datepicker({
               yearRange: "c-75:c+10",
               firstDay: 1,
               dateFormat: 'D, d M yy',
               changeMonth: true,
               changeYear: true,
               altField: altField,
               altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
               defaultDate: new Date(defaultDate),
               onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
                   if (dateText) {       
                        spanElement.html('<strong>'+dateText+'</strong>');
                   }
               }
          });
      })($datepicker, $this, defaultDate, $spanElement);
});

$('.datepicker-button').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().find(".datepicker").datepicker('show');
});
```

Just looking for tips on how I might even debug this!

Comment: add a jsfiddle where we can see the live error

Comment: A fiddle would definitely help. The only thing I notice right now is that you're declaring `$spanElement` but using `spanElement` in the onClose function.

Comment: Will work on re-creating in a fiddle - @Ninsly apologies, I was missing the wrapping function, add now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally figured this out, the issue was with passing the default date in because of the following caveats in IE where NaN breaks the calendar.

Given `defaultDate` would either be '2014,12,18' for saved date or '' for  no date:

- `new Date('')`         // NaN <- Chrome returns Invalid Date, which doesn't break calendar
- `new Date('2014,12,18')` // NaN <- Chrome returns 'Thu Dec 18 2014'
- `new Date(null)`         // Thu Jan 1 00:00:00 UTC 1970
- `new Date(undefined)`    // NaN
- `new Date(2014,12,18)`   // Sun Jan 18 (as JS considers months from 0-11)

Solution was to use either as new Date() params:

- `new Date()`             // current date as expected
- `new Date(2014, 11, 18)` // The Dec 18 2014 as expected

-

```
$('.customDateInput').each(function (idx) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var defaultDate = $this.attr("value").replace(/-/g, ",");
    var $datepicker = $this.parent().find(".datepicker");
    var $spanElement = $this.parent().find(".datepicker-button span");
    (function (picker, altField, defaultDate, spanElement) {

      /** Solution to issue **/
      if(defaultDate) {
          defaultDate = defaultDate.split(',');
          defaultDate = new Date(defaultDate[0], defaultDate[1] - 1, defaultDate[2]);
      } else {
          defaultDate = null;
      }
      /** End of solution **/

      picker.datepicker({
           yearRange: "c-75:c+10",
           firstDay: 1,
           dateFormat: 'D, d M yy',
           changeMonth: true,
           changeYear: true,
           altField: altField,
           altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
           defaultDate: new Date(defaultDate),
           onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
               if (dateText) {       
                    spanElement.html('<strong>'+dateText+'</strong>');
               }
           }
      });
   })($datepicker, $this, defaultDate, $spanElement);
});

$('.datepicker-button').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find(".datepicker").datepicker('show');
});
```